# Permission denied when overwriting files with Codekit

Tags: mamp, virtualhost, overwrite, permission-denied, codekit

Using MAMP Pro, I've set up a virtual host for a site where I run Codekit (http://incident57.com/codekit) to autocompile LESS files to its directory. I've set the owner of the host to www, this interferes with Codekit's preferences in some way though and it isn't able to overwrite any file when compiling (the app displays an "EACESS, permission denied" error). Tried several approaches with setting file permissions for different folders but without success. Ideas?

Comment: I'm running into this. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding to CodeKit the actual folder where your project files exist on disk, not the virtual host that Mamp sets up.